# uninitialized constant Net::HTTPS (NameError)

Tags: ruby, api, https, http-headers

I am trying to pull campaign stats from Clickbank API in ruby.  When I run the sample code Clickbank provided.  I get the following error:

> uninitialized constant Net::HTTPS (NameError).  What am I missing?

Example Code.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'

http = Net::HTTPS.new('api.clickbank.com')
http.use_ssl = false
path = '/rest/1.3/orders/list'

headers = {
  'Authorization' => '<< DEVKEY >>:<< APIKEY>>',
  'Accept' => 'application/json'
}

resp, data = http.get(path, nil, headers)

puts 'Code = ' + resp.code
puts 'Message = ' + resp.message
resp.each {|key, val| puts key + ' = ' + val}
puts data
```

Yes I put my dev and api key into

Comment: Why are you attempting to use `Net::HTTPS` and disabling SSL?

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby 2.4.1 enable ssl as a parameter of Net::HTTP.start

```
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: true)
```

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-HTTPS

Answer (score 3):

Use `Net:HTTP` and enable SSL instead of using `Net::HTTPS` and disabling SSL.

Example:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new('api.clickbank.com')
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't want to disable ssl as that API requires it. I was able to get it working like so based on the documentation for http found here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI('https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/orders/list')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
# set headers on the request
req['Authorization'] = '<< DEVKEY >>:<< APIKEY>>'
req['Accept'] = 'application/json'
# perform the request
resp, data = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}

puts 'Code = ' + resp.code
puts 'Message = ' + resp.message
resp.each {|key, val| puts key + ' = ' + val}
puts data
```

Comment: Progressing but getting this error now:

Code = 400
Message = Bad Request
date = Sun, 05 Jun 2016 03:59:25 GMT
server = Apache
content-length = 362
connection = close
content-type = text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: Your question was about that ssl error message.  I think my answer gets you past that.  I don't have an API key and thus can't test any actual calls.  Here is the documentation for the list api https://api.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/orders2 which lists all the different params you need to send in.  A 400 typically means you are missing some params on the request or are providing bad authentication information.  You also need to filling a real devkey.